# Closed loop plant-control system

Tags: control, control-system

I have the next system, and I want to find the transfer function from d to y.

[image]

So I've got the next equations

$$v = Ce = C(r-y)$$
$$e = r - y$$
$$u = d + v$$
$$y = Pu = Pd + PCr - PCy$$

Now I know that:

$$e/r = \frac{1}{1+PC}$$

So eventaully if I am not mistaken I arrive at:

$$y/d = \frac{P}{1+PC}+\frac{PC}{1+PC} \frac{r}{d}$$

How do I eliminate the dependence on \$r/d\$? i.e, I want y/d to be a function of P and C.

Edit: actually, I arrive at:

$$ y = \frac{P}{1+PC} d + \frac{PC}{1+PC} r$$

So the transfer function from d to y should be: \$\dfrac{P}{1+PC}\$, correct?

Comment: If you want to find the transfer function of y/d you have to ignore r, ie, set it to 0.  It has no place in the y/d transfer function.

Comment: Is this a question about solving a maths problem or are you interested in understanding how to minimize the effect of a disturbance (for example) whilst still allowing the control loop to react to the reference?

Comment: It was a math question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct but an easier method (I think) is to use superposition, first we will suppress r ( i.e. we will ignore r ), then get the transfer function, then suppress d then get the other transfer function, then sum the two up to get the final transfer function.

When we suppress r will then get

$$
\frac{Y}{d} = \frac{P}{1 + PC}
$$

and when we suppress d we will get
$$
  \frac{V}{r} = \frac{C}{1 + PC}
$$

but Y = VP meaning

$$
 \frac{Y}{r} = \frac{PC}{1 + PC}
$$

We the sum up the two values of Y to get the final response of

$$
  Y = \frac{P}{1 + PC}d + \frac{PC}{1 + PC}r
$$

There is no transfer function from d to y because y depends on both d and r, you can't evaluate the value y without knowing both d and r values.

Answer (score 1):

$$ y = \frac{P}{1+PC} d + \frac{PC}{1+PC} r $$
\$r\$ is desired input and \$d\$ is disturbance, so we have to reduce the effect of \$d\$.

If we pick a large gain for C, we have:
$$ if \space C \uparrow \hspace{8 mm}  \frac{P}{1+PC} \downarrow \hspace{8mm} and \hspace{8mm} \frac{PC}{1+PC} \simeq 1 $$
So, $$ y \rightarrow r $$

Be careful about stability: if C is too big, system stability is at risk.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see is that -

$$Y/d = \frac{P}{1+PC} + \frac{PCr}{1+PC}d$$

$$y/d = \frac{PC}{1+PC}(\frac{1}{C} + \frac{r}{d})$$

Hence if I choose my \$C << d/r\$, then my \$1/C + r/d\$ will be almost equal to \$1/C\$. Hence you will have -

$$y/d = \frac{PC}{1+PC}$$